# Is there any way to include index.jsp instead of index.html in react

Tags: reactjs

I started with react using:
**npx create-react-app**

In this I had `index.html`. When bundling using:
  **npm run build**

It returns `index.html`

Is there any way to get **index.jsp** instead of **index.html** in build folder.

Comment: Why do you want react to return a JSP file instead of a HTML?

Comment: I have to do some java code on my landing page. I'm trying to use index.html as my landing page.

Comment: Since JavaServer Pages (JSP) is on the server side and react is mostly for the client side this won't work as you might expect. You can however include react components inside JSP if you have a server that generates your JSP files. Otherwise you most likely have to rewrite your Java code and export it to the server or client side.